# Como eu faço para descobrir se o formulário foi carregado em uma variável ou não?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Toda vez que eu estou mexendo com formulários eu costumo criar uma variável para enviar data por `ajax` futuramente, o problema é que eu sempre me enrolo para descobrir se ele coletou a data ou não, e precisava de alguma forma para descobrir isso.

Meu código está parecido com algo assim:

```js
//Script JS
let form_data = new FormData($("form[name='alpha']")[0]);
```

```html
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<form name="alpha">
  <input type="text" name="campo"></input>
</form>
```

A pergunta é, como eu faço para saber se ele está coletando dados do campo e não gerando um formulário vazio?

Comment: Não deu pra entender direito o que vc quer fazer. Pelo pouco que entendi, vc sabe se algum dado foi enviado pelo comportamento do backend e/ou pelo retorno que espera do AJAX.

Comment: Não... o que eu preciso saber é se existe algum tipo de ```length``` ou ```console log``` para saber se as informações foram carregadas na variável / formData antes de enviar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode iterar o `FormData` e verificar se algum campo do formulário possui valor. Basta iterar a propriedade `.entries()` que retorna para cada campo uma array com um par de valores, sendo o primeiro o `name` e o segundo o `value`. Se um campo estiver vazio, o segundo item da array é vazia.

Por exemplo, se o input `campo` estiver vazio irá gerar a array:

```
['campo', ''] // name, value
```

Com um `for` você itera todas as arrays retornadas verificando com `.includes('')` se alguma dessas arrays possui um item vazio. No primeiro que não encontrar já indica que o `FormaData` carregou valor do formulário. É só fazer uma verificação negativa com `!`.

Veja o código abaixo que irá entender:

```js
$("form[name='alpha']").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   let form_data = new FormData($("form[name='alpha']")[0]);
   let passou;

   for(let par of form_data.entries()){
      if(!par.includes('')){
         passou = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   
   if(!passou){
      console.log("Formulário está vazio. Significa que nenhum campo possui valor.");
      return;
   }
   
   console.log("Formulário possui algum dado. Significa que pelo menos um campo possui valor.");
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="alpha">
   <input type="text" name="campo"></input>
   <input type="text" name="campo2"></input>
   <select name="campo3">
      <option value="">...</option>
      <option value="2">1</option>
   </select>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```